# How to sync Blender & Photoshop?

Tags: texturing

Is it possible to sync Blender & Photoshop for image texturing where you could have both open and view the texture on the model in Blender as you are painting in Photoshop?

Comment: Try using **External Paint Autorefresh Addon**: https://sites.google.com/site/pointatstuffweb/external-paint-autorefresh